# GPU-accelerated sort (~1GB) and merge sort (~100GB)

Tags: c++, sorting, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I'm asking for a c++ library to do GPU-accelerated sort (around 1GB of data) and merge sort (say, around 100GB of data — but the size do not matter, because merge is a stream algorithm). License have to be LGPL, BSD or like this. I greatly prefer OpenCL because of portability (but I also interested in links to CUDA libraries). I appreciate links to papers and blog posts on this subject.

#### Some background (please correct me if I wrong):

2-way merge sort of 1GB (that is, 128 000 000 of 8-bytes entities) will consume approximately log<sub>2</sub>(128 000 000)·1G = 27GB of memory bandwidth, that is around 1 second on modern CPU with *sequential* memory bandwidth of ~30GB/s. (Any non-merge sort seems to take much longer time, because non-sequential memory access is slower in 10-100 times).

Although I am not familiar with modern GPU, I suspect that merge sort of 1GB will take 0.2 second or even less, because typical GPU memory bandwidth is around 150GB/s, like AMD/ATI 58xx (see, for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Evergreen_.28HD_5xxx.29_series)

That is at least 5x speedup. (The time to transfer 1GB over 16x PCI-E 2.0 is around 0.125s, but it seems possible to make PCI transfers in parallel with sorting; however, this may require 2GB or 3GB of video-card memory instead of 1GB).

I suspect even more speed-up due to more-than-2-way merge sort or some sort, suitable for GPU.

Comment: I hope to be wrong, but IO in big data problem (the 100GB part) will kill any gains you'll get from using GPU in the small problem (the 1GB part), even if you use multiple SSD, unless the comparison procedure is so complex it needs GPU. Second problem is sending data to GPU and receiving it back—it's much slower than pure GPU memory bandwdith. But I'm curious what answers will you get.

Comment: @liori At least, 100 of 1GB-gpu-sorted-blocks may be merged by CPU, not GPU (it's around 7 passes, so it really seems that PCI transfer will be a bottleneck). However, there may exist a clever trick, that I am not aware of.

Comment: Also, not an answer and might be barely related, as they're mostly using clusters and not GPUs, but you might find some ideas on http://sortbenchmark.org/

Comment: After browsing through some of the papers I found it interesting that what they mostly optimize is the IO, which would support my worries. Hopefully you'll find a way though.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) ?

From the project page:

> Thrust is a parallel algorithms library which resembles the C++
>   Standard Template Library (STL). Thrust's high-level interface greatly
>   enhances developer productivity while enabling performance portability
>   between GPUs and multicore CPUs. Interoperability with established
>   technologies (such as CUDA, TBB and OpenMP) facilitates integration
>   with existing software. Develop high-performance applications rapidly
>   with Thrust!

License is Apache so it should suit you.

Comment: My early edit that adds my OpenCL preference mysteriously disappeared, so I had to make it again. Anyway, thanks for links. For the sake of completeness: Q: When will Thrust support OpenCL? A: The primary barrier to OpenCL support is the lack of an OpenCL compiler and runtime with support for C++ templates (e.g., something similar to nvcc and the CUDA Runtime). These features are necessary to achieve close coupling of host and device codes.